# What Does a double assignment in a VB.NET assignment accomplish?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I (new to VB.NET) am doing some code maintenance on a function that sometimes throws an exception "error converting string "False" (or "True") to type Integer."  What I found was something equivalent to this

someVal is a string, someFun1 returns an Integer and someFun2 takes an Integer as a parameter

```
...
someVal = someVal = someFun1()
...
someFun2(someVal)
...
```

What I think might be happening is that it is trying to assign     someFun1's return value into someVal, then perform a bool check as to whether someVal has changed - but I don't think that is what needs to be done.

My question is - does this double assignment (someVal = someVal = someFun1()) accomplish anything that I don't know about in VB.NET?

another note: I realize there are implicit casts of integer to string and back to integer, but that shouldn't be causing any problems, because the values should always hold a numerical value (which can be implicitly cast back and forth from Integer and String, right?) not True or False - as far as I can tell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion here is that the equals operator `=` is the same as the assignment operator `=` in VB.NET. In C#, the code above would be equivalent to

```
someVal = someVal == someFun1();
```

where the boolean equals operator `==` is carried out first, and the result is inserted into `someVal`. This fails, because `someVal` is `int`, not `bool`.

In other words, the runtime is comparing `someVal` with the return value of `someFun1()`, returning `True` or `False`, and failing to cast that to an integer. This isn't a "double assignment" - it's just an inline representation of

```
If someVal = someFun1() Then
    someVal = True
Else
    someVal = False
End If
```

where it is much more obvious that we're trying to give an `Integer` variable a value of type `Boolean`.

Comment: I just realized I got the types of your variables wrong, but the same principles apply for strings etc.